# How to write a Promise as an Observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise, observable

I am new to Angular and just worked with promises but as far as I know I should use Observables but I have some problems here.

So my code with a promise to do a GET request looks like this:

```
apiGet(method: any, query: any): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var otmAPI =
        this.url +
        method +
        "?apikey=" +
        this.API_KEY;
      if (query !== undefined) {
        otmAPI += "&" + query;
      }
      fetch(otmAPI)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => resolve(data))
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log("Fetch Error :-S", err);
        });
    });
  }
```

So far my Observable method looks like this:

```
getPois(method: any, query: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.url +
      method +
      "?apikey=" +
      this.API_KEY).pipe(
        tap(data => {
          console.log(data)
          if (query !== undefined) {
            data += "&" + query;
          }
        })
      );
  }
```

I don't know if I did it correctly but it works, the problem is just I cannot append the query.
For the promise I can append it (the if-block will append the query)
But when I try to do this in the Angular way with a pipe and then tap (to be honest, I don't know whether to use tap or map or so) but here it doesn't work! I get a Bad Request.

Would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piping is used when you have to chain multiple observables together.
Looks like you want to add query parameter in the URL based on a condition .
You  can do something like this :

```
getPois(method: any, query: any): Observable<any> {
    let otmAPI = `${this.url}${method}?apikey=${this.API_KEY}`;
    if (query !== undefined) {
      otmAPI += "&" + query;
    }
    return this.http.get(otmAPI);
  }
```

then in your component subscribe to it :

```
 this.getPois("method","query").subscribe(res=>{
      console.log('success',res)
    })
```

Comment: Ahhh I understand. Okay so I used pipe in the wrong way.. Got it! Thanks a lot! This is the answer I wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `HttpParams` to add query parameters - it is the recommended (and of course, cleaner) approach
2. Use `tap` specifically if you need to inspect the returned data. But in general, you can add any operation here which will be executed along the observable's execution pipeline
3. Use `map` specifically if you need to modify the returned data in someway before returning it to a subscriber. But in general you add other operations here (if you need any) which will be executed along the observable's execution pipeline. You must return a value from this operator.

```js
getPois(method: any, query: any): Observable<any> {

    let options = {
        params: new HttpParams()
            .set('apikey', this.API_KEY)
            .set('someParam', someValue)
            .set('someOtherParam', someOtherValue)
    }

    return this.http.get(this.url + method, options)
        .pipe(
            tap(data => {
                console.log(data);
            }),
            map(data => {
                let modifiedData = // some modification to data
                return modifiedData
            })
        )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using fetch I'd recommend you to work with HttpClientModule so in your service you can do as following to do api requests:

```
apiCall() {
    return this.http.get<any>(`url`).toPromise();
  }
```

The httpClient usually returns a promise but if you prefer to work with promises you can use `.toPromise` to transform the result into a promise.

Before work with the HttpClientModule you first have to import it into your module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        // import HttpClientModule after BrowserModule.
        HttpClientModule,
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
      ],
      bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

And then you have to inject it into your service as follow:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
}
```

Here you have more detailed information: https://angular.io/guide/http